# Calculate natural log response ratio for each level of a treatment

Tags: r, logging

I have two predictor variables (treatment 1 and treatment 2):

-treatment1: 2 levels (U and C) This treatment is nested in treatment 2.

-treatment2: 7 levels (level1, level2, level3, level4, level5, level6, level7), each with 3 replicates

level 6 is my control

And three response variables: a, b and c

This is data for four years: 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019

My question is: How do I calculate natural response ratio for each response variable in each treatment2 using level 6 as my reference, this separated for U and C, in each year?

For example, what is the natural log response ratio of level 1 in relation to level 6 (control) in U vs. C? Next, what is the natural log response ratio of level 2 in relation to level 6 (control) in U vs. C?... and so on.

This is a subset of my dataframe (df) with dummy response values:

[image]

I really appreciate any help with this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't have much experience with the log response ratio but the definition as per [link](http://search.r-project.org/library/SingleCaseES/html/LRR.html) is :

> The response ratio parameter is the ratio of the mean level of the outcome during phase B to the mean level of the outcome during phase A. The log response ratio is the natural logarithm of the response ratio. This effect size is appropriate for outcomes measured on a ratio scale (so that zero corresponds to the true absence of the outcome.

#### Simple example

```
A <- c(20, 20, 26, 25, 22, 23)
B <- c(28, 25, 24, 27, 30, 30, 29)

df = data.frame(y = c(A,B),
                x = c(rep("A",times=length(A)),rep("B",times=length(B))))

lm_out <- lm(y ~ x,data=df)

beta_0 <- coef(lm_out)[1] 
beta_1 <- coef(lm_out)[2] 

# log response ratio:
log(beta_0 + beta_1) - log(beta_0)
```

#### Your question

1. Stratify your dataset by year and treatment 1. This is equivalent to adding three-way interaction effects - which is what you are suggesting. You could fit a three-way interaction if that is the more appropriate model for your use-case.
2. Numerator: Add up the Intercept and coefficient for your level of interest (say Level 1)
3. Denominator: Just the intercept
4. Log response ratio = log (Numerator/Denominator)

Comment: Thanks @jvargh, but I think what I am trying to do is something like: ln(a in level 1 / a in level 6)

Comment: Yes, so when you fit a linear regression stratified by year and treat1, your intercept will be mean value of your outcome in treat2's reference category (Level 6)